# Image in google map info box doesn't show

Tags: javascript, image, google-maps-markers

I am working in VS 2015.

I need to create a mark to have click on event which pop up an image and info from content.

I've tried everything but the image that i have in that location doesn't seem to work.

This is what I've done so far:

```
<script>
  // Declare a varibale for map
  var map;
  // Get lattitude and longitude of Canberra Centre
  var canberraCentre = new google.maps.LatLng(-35.2792284, 149.1321033);

  // Initialise the map
  function initMap() {
    // Define the properties for Canberra Centre map
    var canberraMap = {
      center: canberraCentre,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // Create a map object for Canberra Centre
    // using canberraMap and the <div> element with id="googleMap"
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), canberraMap);

    // Add markers
    addKinnMarker(map);

  }

  // Kinn marker
  function addKinnMarker(map) {
    var Kinn = new google.maps.LatLng(-35.279527, 149.133558);
    var markerKinn = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: Kinn,
    });

    markerKinn.setMap(map);

    var contentKinn =
      ' <h1>Kinn</h1>' +
      ' <img src="D:\Uni\WDP\Assignment_1\Restaurants\src\Restaurants\wwwroot\images\Kinn\KinnLogosmall.JPG" border="0" width="100px" height="30" align="left">' +
      ' <p>Kinn Thai Restaurant <br/>' +
      'It is located on 125 Bunda Street in the Canberra Centre<br>' +
      '<a href="http://www.kinnrestaurant.com.au/canberra/">Vist Kinn for more information</a>' +
      ' </p>';

      var infoKinn = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentKinn
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(markerKinn, 'click',
        function () {
          infoKinn.open(map, markerKinn);
        });
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can set reference to image like that (the src attribute). Try to save your image inside your project directory and then change the path accordingly.

Comment: It is inside the project directory in fact... it is where all image saved. All image work as normal page image but not in this situation.

Comment: Try to use relative path... e.g.: /images/Kinn/KinnLogosmall.JPG and use this type of backslash /

Comment: OMG... that's it. Thanks so much. That fixed it.